# Jackson two classes issue

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

My code is working and its all good but what bothers me is that for every single response i have two classes.

This is how json looks like, there is a main object that have response object that always different.

```
object{
...
...
response{
...
...
}
}
```

Here the class with properties, so when there is auth operation api call i get an object and inside there is another response which will present the information mentioned below(accountID,authToken)

```
public class AuthResponse implements IResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private String accountID;
    @JsonProperty
    private String authToken;

   // IResponse just have a validation method
}
```

Here is a wrapper with AuthResponse that is called response so that jackson can locate it

```
public class NowOSAuthResponse extends NowOSResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private AuthResponse response;

    //can be replaced with @Getter
    @Override
    public IResponse getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

And finally here the main object that contain abstract interface so that every response has its own return object

```
public abstract class NowOSResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private String version;
    @JsonProperty
    private String operation;
    @JsonProperty
    private String status;

    public abstract IResponse getResponse();
```

So i wanted to know if there is a way how to give back the response object without create two classes. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can helps you:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode root = mapper.createObjectNode();
    root.putPOJO("response", Map.of("accountID", "id", "authToken", "token"));
    root.put("version", "v1");

    mapper.writer().writeValue(bos, root);
    System.out.println(new String(bos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

or

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode root = mapper.createObjectNode();
    var response = Map.of("response", Map.of("accountID", "id", "authToken", "token"), "version", "v1");

    mapper.writer().writeValue(bos, response);
    System.out.println(new String(bos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Output: {"response":{"authToken":"token","accountID":"id"},"version":"v1"}

Comment: Hmm that possibly could work, but that would require ObjectMapper and some lines of code, however that is a good idea, maybe Jackson have some annotation or something to make it easy and not to have those lines , thank you for your fomment

Comment: You can create a single map with all your fields, and then you can serialise the map directly See my updated answer